# Exception Handling with Traceback Repo not Found Error

Tags: python, python-3.x, exception, traceback

I would like Python to handle the exception for OSError and `Traceback` from repo not found, how can I accomplish this correctly?

Here is my code.

```
try: 
    os.mkdir(res)
    print("cloning")
    repo = git.Repo.clone_from(item['href'], to_path = res)
except OSError, Exception:
    continue
```

Here is the exception that I would like python to take care of.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test.py", line 34, in <module>
    repo = git.Repo.clone_from(item['href'], to_path = res)
  File "/home/abc/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/git/repo/base.py", line 1020, in clone_from
    return cls._clone(git, url, to_path, GitCmdObjectDB, progress, multi_options, **kwargs)
  File "/home/abc/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/git/repo/base.py", line 966, in _clone
    finalize_process(proc, stderr=stderr)
  File "/home/abc/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/git/util.py", line 333, in finalize_process
    proc.wait(**kwargs)
  File "/home/abc/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/git/cmd.py", line 412, in wait
    raise GitCommandError(self.args, status, errstr)
git.exc.GitCommandError: Cmd('git') failed due to: exit code(128)
  cmdline: git clone -v https://anonscm.debian.org/git/pkg-fedora-ds/389-console.git 389-console
  stderr: 'Cloning into '389-console'...
fatal: repository 'https://anonscm.debian.org/git/pkg-fedora-ds/389-console.git/' not found
'
```

Any guidance is very much appreciated.

Comment: Please provide the full traceback (with any sensitive info redacted).

Comment: The error of repo not found stems from `GitCommandError`. I'd suggest you catch that first. I also suspect that `GitCommandError` contains other errors in addition to repo not found. Thus after `GitCommandError` is captured, you might need to regex "repository xxx not found" in the error message to single out the repo not found error.